# Sending message to different thread

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, multithreading

Is there any API to send message to a thread?
Basically I have only threadId available and I want to send a custom message to that thread.

Comment: What threading model are you using? WinAPI? pthread?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PostThreadMessage. Not very reliable though.

See The Old New Thing blog [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2009/09/30/9901065.aspx) and [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2005/04/26/412116.aspx) for details on why. Basically modal message loops make a mess of the whole idea. Since a message posted to a thread has no window handle, calling DispatchMessage will throw the message away. Any modal loop you run - directly or indirectly - will call DispatchMessage, so a good proportion of the time this strategy will fail and your message will disappear into the ether.

Comment: Most important sentence from those two articles: "If you need to communicate reliably with a thread that also displays UI, then create a hidden window and send or post messages to that window."

Comment: Of course, if _all you have is a ThreadId_, that suggestion won't work either.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [QueueUserAPC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684954(VS.85).aspx) if the target thread is alertable